# HTTP outbounds to Facebook normal?

Tags: facebook, http, firewall, logging

I'm not a facebook user.. nobdoby in the house is that I know of. But when I check our firewall outbounds I see a lot of hits to 69.63.189.11 which is a facebook address I've checked the laptop and don't see any toolbars with facebook links.  It's not always, just during certain times of day when my kids are surfing. I also see sites like Amazon and google in the mix, but also alot of hits to 23.45.65.33 and 48 akamai.com.

Does this mean they are likely accessing facebook? Or only that some sites have links to Facebook images?

Comment: I can't answer your question, but I can tell you that akamai offer CDN services, and facebook uses that. And so, content from akamai can mean static facebook files (images, javascripts, style files, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many websites are adopting Facebook like buttons (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/). This is probably what you're seeing being hit.